# Why is VSCode HTML Does Not Load Page Into Chrome

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use HTML in VSCode. This is my settings.json code:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "html": " cd $dir && start chrome $fileName"
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runhaskell",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "sml": "cd $dir && sml $fileName"
    }
}
```

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Yo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the file saved as "woof.html".

This is what chrome shows.

[image]

Could someone please explain why this is not working? I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssF-OdOnf58

Comment: maybe try changing the command to run `start chrome file:///$fileName`

Comment: @Cornelius-Figgle oops..... So the file name would be "woof.html"?

Comment: In Chrome (and most browsers), to access local files you need to type `file:///` before the normal path in order to view the file. I haven't played about much with VS Code settings like that, but I assumed that `$filename` was a variable that VSC handles to run the current file EDIT: so yes, if you wanted to manually test opening `file:///full/path/to/woof.html` should work